# How to disable the Plasma 5 hot zone at bottom left?

Tags: plasma

In KDE Plasma 5(.24.7), the lower left corner of the screen is a hot zone -- moving the mouse there pops up a panel showing all windows in the workspace, where you can select one. (Apparently this is un-screenshot-able; otherwise, I'd post an image to clarify.)

I find this behavior not very helpful and I would like to disable it. However, this display has no title, hence, no way to infer what it's called in order to search for system settings. Web searches for "plasma lower left" or "plasma bottom left" do not turn up anything useful (especially since older Plasma versions used this hot zone for something completely different, as evidenced by search results that described totally different features).

How do I turn this off?

Comment: Might be better asking in a kde forum? http://forum.kde.org/

Comment: @Will why would that be?

Comment: "Might be better asking in a kde forum?" Disallows registration from mainland China (not the only support forum to discriminate geographically in this way).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Settings --> Workspace behavior --> Screen edges

Disselect  "Present windows"

[image]